# Handling Id for multiple entities in solr/Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm using solr dataimporthandler to index multiple tables which are actors, actress, directors and movies. Each of these tables have an id field which starts from 1. Solr's schema has an unique key field. Does this field need to be unique for the entire index or just the entity? For example, if there are both an actor and movie with id 1, will solr be able to recognize them or I'll have to make a global unique key for each entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be unique across the entire index. This is easily achieved if you just create an id by appending some prefix per table to the table id. For example, when select-ing from actors table:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ACT-', id) as solrid, ...
```

And index solrid as the doc id.

Comment: so what will happen if the id field is not unique? will the document be added or replaced?